# Word for talking to a stranger with the purpose of befriending them

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, dialects

I'm looking to translate a word from my local dialect (Algerian) to English.
The exact word is `dsara` which means trying hard to talk to a stranger with the purpose of befriending them with no mutual feeling.
An example of this would be a taxi driver who tends to talk to his customers about personal things and try to befriend them quickly.
A typical response would be:

> "Hey am not your friend, just a customer so don't [missing word] me"

I hope I made my point clear

Comment: Even if you find the right word, such a statement would come off as abrupt and perhaps rude, maybe even hostile. Certainly it would be presumptuous. A better approach might be to say something like "No offense, but I don't feel like talking right now" or "I have things on my mind and can't talk right now, sorry." If the driver doesn't take the hint you can make the point more strongly: "Hey, I can't talk with you right now, okay?"

Comment: @Robusto The taxi story is just a made-up example, the word is excessively used in my country everywhere, even online on social media where people are actually looking for friends ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So why would you make up an example that is not indicative of what you're looking for?

Comment: @Robusto I do believe his example is close to what he is looking for - yet it is a complicated evolving social more that older generations like us are  less likely to perceive of at all (or realize we're curmudgeons if we do) and younger generations  who might not agree but are more aware of a "political influence of speech" through things like microagressions, pronoun wars,  and "normalizing".  Jimmy Fallon being a cordial host to major party nominee Trump is still seen as unforgivable malpractice - despite that being entirely the model and tradition of the show.

Comment: There would be no use for such a word, which is why there isn't one. It is contrary to (normal) human nature to react adversely to a genuine approach of friendship. Maybe sociopaths have a vocabulary of their own, but it has (understandably) not become mainstream idiom.

Comment: I have corrected the English in your title. You can't use the infinitive here. Your energy may be better spent in that direction.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying for me: is the intention of this conversation *actually* to form a lasting friendship, or is it more a conversation to create a friendly *feeling* when stuck together for a time? For context, the taxi driver scenario you mentioned is more the "friendly feeling" type, at least in my experience with US taxi drivers.

Comment: @NigelJ I wish what you say was true, I agree that friendly small talk is core to human decency - yet, our culture wars are wandering  - perhaps these links are only related to compliments but the authors seem to be taking a larger sweep to me. https://slate.com/human-interest/2018/05/why-taking-a-compliment-is-so-hard.html https://slate.com/culture/2018/05/tina-fey-rachel-bloom-and-the-death-of-male-approval-in-comedy.html  I really don't know what to think, but there are links to more in those articles

Comment: For a _false_ friendship attempt 'ingratiate' is a good fit.

Comment: I can only assume there's a whole lot of Americans in the comments above. When I lived in the US as an Australian, I found strangers chit-chatting with me infuriating and presumptuous. Don't generalise about human nature. (Also: negative vs positive politeness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness#Types.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[To cozy up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cozy+up).

> - To become friendly with someone, usually in an attempt to obtain something.
>
>   - *Since I'm deciding who gets the promotion, Crystal has been cozying up to me by buying me coffee all week*.

also [flatter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flatter) comes close to what you are referring to:

> - to praise someone in order to make them feel attractive or important, sometimes in a way that is not sincere.

and, as suggested by MetaEd, [ingratiate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ingratiate):

> - to make someone like you by praising or trying to please them.

(Cambridge a Dictionary)

Comment: `flatter` seems to be more semantic, as they are not trying to obtain anything, thanks for the help

Comment: Consider adding *ingratiate*.

Comment: Consider adding 'to chat up someone'

Comment: OP's *befriending* fits better in fact.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a wonderful fit, but *chit-chat* is the expression that comes to mind:

> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chit-chat
>   informal conversation about matters that are not important

(That fits the social function of *dsara* but not the content)

The other is *overshare*:

> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overshare to tell people too much personal information about yourself

(That fits the content of *dsara* but not the social function)